# How do I Avoiding Looping back to lines in code?

Tags: python

I am self-teaching myself python and have run into a problem that I can not seem to find a way around.
I have created a piece of code that compares an entered password to one stored in a database.
My code should have two possibilities.

1) If the password is correct. 
The user is prompted to enter a new password and then the prompt to enter the password must appear again (This time accepting the new password).

2)If the password is incorrect the user will be prompted to enter the password until the correct password is entered.

In VBS I used to be able to use the `GOTO` command.
I am not sure if this is available in Python and if it is I would like to avoid using it as it creates a very illogical hard to follow the program.

```
password = "@123"
entry = input("Please Input The Password:")

if (password == entry):
    entry = input("Password correct you may enter a new password.")
else:
    entry = input("Password Incorrect, Try again.")
```

Comment: notice @Eric Jin answer. also GOTO command is bad and obsolete, you should learn more about while 
and for loops.

Answer (score 2):

There are various ways you could complete this. Here is a simple way you could achieve it using while loop and break statement.

```
password = "@123"
while(True):
    entry = raw_input("Please Input The Password: ")
    if (password == entry):
        print("Password correct you may enter a new password.")
        break
    else:
        print("Password Incorrect, Try again.")
```

Hope it helped.

Comment: Instead of `while(True):`, use `while True:`. The parens aren’t needed.

Answer (score 1):

```py
while password != entry: # Executes until (password == entry), and does not execute if it is met, even for the first time.
    print('Sorry, wrong password.')
    entry = input('Enter password >') # or other source of data
print('Correct!')
```

Edit: additional ways you can do this:

```py
while True: # forever loop, but
    entry = input('Enter password >') # or other source of data
    if password == entry:
        print('Correct!') # you can also put this outside of the loop
        break # exit the loop no matter what
        # do not put code after the break statement, it will not run!
    print('Sorry, wrong password') # will execute only if password != entry, break ignores the rest of the code in the loop
```

Comment: People do the strangest things.  I believe that as intended, both of these "answers" define infinite loops if `password != entry`.  The second answer, as formatted, won't even compile.  I'm guessing that maybe these are supposed to be templates and not complete code, but that isn't at all clear.  And yet this got two upvotes.  Bizarre.

Comment: This is python 3, I copy+pasted from my IDE, what do you mean?

Comment: What do you mean "what do I mean"?  Nothing changes in your loop. If `password != entry`, you'll just loop forever.  Nothing ever changes the value of `entry` so that it can become `password` and the loop can exit.

Comment: Well sure but I am expecting people to be able to put their own code, but if you insist here you go.

Comment: It makes no sense to post code that doesn't work, and has no clear indication of why that is so.  I didn't insist on anything.  I was just telling you my thoughts, and those shared by most of the community I'd think, that you don't want post code that seems to stand alone and yet has fundamental problems with it.  If you expected it to only be a template, you should have put some comments in it , on their own lines, like `// ... put your own code here that queries the user and sets "entry" ...` . 
A series of dots seems to be the accepted way to say that you expect the reader to add code....

Comment: BTW, I think you want to add one indent level to the last line of your second example

Comment: oops....replace those two forward slashes in my comment example above with '#'.  Was thinking in Java vs Python.

Comment: I agree with your statements, thanks for that (and another edit...)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest to make a function with a while statement.

```
password = "@123"
def login():
    while True:
        answer = input("Please Input The Password:")
        if answer == password:
            print("Password correct you may enter a new password.")
        else:
            print("Password Incorrect, Try again.")
            break
login()
```

Comment: You can never get out of this `while` loop.  I think you want a `break` instead of a `continue`, and it would seem to make more sense to put it on the other side of the `else`. @GalpearTech has the version of your answer that is actually useful.